# Obtener la cantidad de elementos comunes de dos listas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy implemantentado códgo en python para este enunciado:
Implementar una función llamada cantAparicionesSub que
tome como parámetro dos listas de enteros, y que calcule la cantidad de
elementos de la primera lista que se encuentran también en la segunda. Además devolver una lista con los elementos comunes entre las dos listas.

Para ello escribí este código:

```
def cantAparicionesSub(lista1, lista2):
    lista_final = []
    contador = 0

    for i in range( len(lista1) ):
        for j in range( len(lista2) ):
            if lista1[i] == lista2[j]:
                lista_final.append(i)
                contador = contador + 1
    print("Cantidad de elementos comunes: ", contador)
    return contador, lista_final
```

Probando, por ejemplo con:

```
listaA = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2]
listaB= [1]
res = cantAparicionesSub(listaA, listaB)
print(res)
```

Da como resultado 6 elementos de la listaA que estan en B. Pero la lista de elemntos comunes da: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Siempre genera una lista conel incremento de i y nó he logrado obtener la lista esperada.

Comment: a `lista_final` efectivamente le estas agregando `i`. Si pruebas algo como `lista_final.append(lista1[i])`?

Comment: ¿La necesidad de los ciclos `for` obedece a un requerimiento del ejercicio? Te pregunto por que es mucho más sencillo de resolverlo usando comprensión de listas.

Comment: Javier, funciona, pero no entiendo por qué debería ir lista1[i]

Comment: Los ciclos  for los usé como manera preliminar para resolver el enunciado. El enunciado no pedía usar ciclos for. No conozco el método de compresión de listas.

Comment: porque `i` representa la posición del elemento y `lista[i]` es el elemento, y lo que necesitas es agregar es el elemento no su posición.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se explican bien algunas cosas. Por ejemplo: ¿Si la "listaB" tiene más de un elemento que coincide con la "listaA", se retorna más de un contador o el total global de repeticiones? ¿La "listaB" puede tener elementos que se repiten? ¿La lista final solo trae la coincidencia de cada elemento, o todas las veces que está en la "listaA"?

Para contar la cantidad de coincidencias de un elemento que hay en una lista, existe la función `count` https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Bueno, como ya puse, el problema tiene ambigüedades, pero este código te puede ayudar a encontrar lo quieres si no te sirve exactamente.
Retorna la cantidad de coincidencias en una lista y otra lista con los elementos coincidentes.

```
def cantAparicionesSub(lista1, lista2):
    contador = 0
    lista_final = []
    for n in lista2:
        num_ocurrencias = lista1.count(n)
        if num_ocurrencias > 0:
            contador += num_ocurrencias
            lista_final.append(n)
    return contador, lista_final

listaA = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2]
listaB = [1]
res = cantAparicionesSub(listaA, listaB)
print(res)
```

Resultado

```
(6, [1])
```

(6 veces se repite el elemento 1)

Otro ejemplo, para las listas

```
listaA = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3]
listaB = [1,3,5]
```

El resultado sería:

```
(9, [1, 3])
```

(9 veces se repiten en conjunto el 1 y el 3)

Answer (score 0):

La linea de codigo que esta generando el problema es:

lista_final.append(i)

Esta linea esta agregando la posición "i" donde esta el elemento " lista1[i]" a la lista_final , para agregar el elemento de la lista1 en la lista_final el código seria el siguiente:

lista_final.append(lista1[i])   ó  lista_final.append(lista2[i])

Suerte.